# where to put option for event for edit/delete/add form_editing in initialization

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

like the title..
where should I put option for event for edit/delete/add form_editing in initialization?
in which array?

I used to create some buttons like some of the demos, assigned/bind them after initialization. but now I want to use their default button. but I got difficulties on binding the event of the dialog box like "beforeSubmit/afterSubmit" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically one don't call [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) and [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow) directly. Instead of that one uses [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) to add buttons in the navigator bar. The `navGrid` method has `click` event handler with calls [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow) or [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow) (or other) depend on which button the user click.

So if you use `navGrid` too you should use `prmEdit`, `prmAdd` and `prmDel` parameters to specify you custom callback function like `beforeSubmit`/`afterSubmit`:

```
$("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager',
    {/*navGrid options*/},
    {/*edit options and callbacks*/},
    {/*add options and callbacks*/},
    {/*add options and callbacks*/});
```